# Regular expression in Hive - Get number after specific text

Tags: regex, hive, expression

How can I use regular expressions in order to get the number 4968 from the following text?

```
"category_path":["XXX1430","XXX109026","XXX3120","XXX4968","XXX377357"]
```

Many thanks!

Comment: What can vary from that string?

Comment: The numbers' length, the rest will be always the same.

Comment: If you know the number 4968 why do you want to get it from the text? Do you want that specific number, or you want the number following the Xs, or you want the number following the Xs in the 4th position of the array?

Comment: I want the number following the Xs in the 4th position of the array. It's important that the Xs are next to the 'category_path' string, since I have XXXs in other parts as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex: `category_path":\[(?:"[X]+\d+",){3}"[X]+\K\d+`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/m1cFU1/2)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a regex you could capture 4968 in a group `(\d+)`.

[`"category_path":\["XXX\d+"(?:,"XXX\d+"){2},"XXX(\d+)"(?:,"XXX\d+")*\]`](https://regex101.com/r/ifmjq9/1/)

Explanation

- `"category_path":\[` Match literally
- `"XXX\d+"` Match XXX digits pattern without a coma
- `(?:,"XXX\d+"){2}` repeat the XXX digits pattern with a comma 2 times
- `"XXX(\d+)"` match `"XXX` and capture one or more digits in a group `(\d+)` and match a `"`
- `(?:,"XXX\d+")*\]` match the pattern zero or more times and the closing `]`